# Is it safe to use OAuth2 password flow in an web app?

Tags: spring-security, oauth-2.0

I have a web app based on Vue. My authorization server and resource server are 
all in one program based on Spring Security.

However, I need to put `client_id` and `client_secret` in the URL paramter to get token from `/oauth/token` endpoint so that I can login from the web app.

Is it proper to expose the `client_id` and `client_secret` of my web app?

Am I using Spring Security / OAuth2 in a wrong way?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are right to be worried - the client secret should not be exposed in a client-side web app. Have you considered using the Implicit flow rather than the Password flow? The former does not need a client secret to be known by the client.

On another note, maybe you do not need OAuth 2.0 flow here at all. One option would be to simply send the username/password to the server and get a token and not worry about client IDs/secrets at all. This will depend on whether you are planning to expose your server to other apps as well. If it's just this app, I don't see any particular advantage of implementing an OAuth 2.0 flow.